# "ModelForm has no model class specified."

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to create a Register Form but I couldn't find any solution "ModelForm has no model class specified." for this error. I didn't use ModelForm but I take this error. Can somebody explain me why am I taking this error and how can I fix it

// views.py//

```
        from django.shortcuts import render
        from .forms import RegisterForm
        from django.contrib import messages
        from django.contrib.auth import login as dj_login

        def register(request):
            if request.method == "POST":

                form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                    user = {
                        "username": form.cleaned_data["username"],
                        "email": form.cleaned_data["email"],
                        "phone": form.cleaned_data["phone"],
                        "password1": form.cleaned_data["password1"],
                        "password2": form.cleaned_data["password2"]
                    }
                    user = form.save()
                    dj_login(request,user)
                    messages.success(request,"You have completed registration successfully.")
                    return render(request,"index.html",{"user":user})
                else:
                    messages.info(request,"You couldn't complete registrations!")
            else:
                form = RegisterForm()
                return render(request,"register.html",{"form":form})
```

// forms.py //

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    phone = forms.IntegerField(required=True)

    class Meta():
        user = User
        fields = ["username","email","phone","password1","password2"]

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegisterForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        user.phone = self.cleaned_data["phone"]

        if commit:
           user.save()
        return user
```

Comment: it is possible to write in class Meta: model = User, instead of user = User.

Comment: Yes, it fixed. Thank you, I spent more than 2 hours and I couldn't see it.

Comment: upvote if I create an answer?

Comment: I am not allowed to upvote